# How do I get the Category names from a Page/Template on MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I want to be able to use the Categories of a page in a layout of another page.

Something like this:

```
[[Page1]] content: {{:page1}} 
[[Page1]] Categories: {{:page1|GETCATEGORIES}}
```

Here is page1:

```
Black

<noinclude>
[[Category:Color]]
[[Category:Dark]]
</noinclude>
```

I want the output to be:
content: black Categories: Color Dark

Answer (score 2):

You will need an extension for this. Here are some options:

1. [Semantic MediaWiki](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki) allows you to do queries like that.
2. A simpler, but more limited way of doing the same thing would be to install the [CategoryTree](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aCategoryTree) extension. Then you can write `{{#categorytree:page1}}` to show categories for page1
3. Depending on your need, the best approach might be to write your own [parser function](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aParser_functions) extension, that adds a parser function to list the categories of a page.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the semantic mediawiki, you can also use dynamic page lists and rely on its [addcategories](http://semeb.com/dpldemo/index.php?title=DPL:Manual_-_DPL_parameters:_Controlling_output_volume#addcategories) parameter. The DPL extension is quite powerful and is an alternative to semantic mediawiki (although the latter is a cleaner and better option if you have a choice).